# How to add a JTable to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, gridbaglayout

my question can seem a bit stupid but everytime i use swing, i got problems with tables. So im working on a school project, and i need to add some JTable to a JPanel with a GridBagLayout, but i can't see the JTable im Adding to my panel.

Here is the code :

```
public class MainView extends JFrame {

    private static Dimension dimensionFenetre = new Dimension(1980, 1000);
    Object[][] team = {
        {"France", "80"},
        {"Germany", "80"},
        {"Italy", "80"},
        {"England", "80"}
};

String  titleColumn[] = {"Team", "Overall"};

public MainView() {

    JPanel panelFenetre = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    add(panelFenetre);
    setVisible(true);
    panelFenetre.setVisible(true);
    setSize(dimensionFenetre);

    panelFenetre.add(getTable1(), getTable1Constraints());
}

private JTable getTable1() {

    JTable table = new JTable(team, titleColumn);
    table.setVisible(true);

    return table;
}

private GridBagConstraints getTable1Constraints() {

    GridBagConstraints gbcTable1 = new GridBagConstraints(
            0, 1,
            1, 1,
            1, 1,
            GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
            GridBagConstraints.NONE,
            new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0),
            0, 0);

    return gbcTable1;
  }
}
```

And a simple Main :

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainView mainView = new MainView();
  }
}
```

If someone, have some clues, it will be really great.

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't call `setSize()` but rather `pack()` after adding components to let the layout managers do their jobs.
2. Add the JTable to a JScrollPane first, then add that to the GUI.
3. Most important, don't call `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame until **after** adding all components.

Works fine for me:

```
public MainView() {
    JPanel panelFenetre = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    add(panelFenetre);

    // setVisible(true);
    // panelFenetre.setVisible(true);
    // setSize(dimensionFenetre);

    panelFenetre.add(new JScrollPane(getTable1()), getTable1Constraints());        
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: First, thanks for taking the time to answer me. So i have follow your indications. Now i can see the border of the JScrollPane i guess, if i call `setPreferedSize()` on it. But i can't see the table with the data on it.

Comment: @SebastienMURE: you must be doing something wrong as it works fine for me. Please see edits above.

Comment: Yes it seems that it was a problem in the way i was creating the JScrollPane, everything is ok now, thanks a lot.